Export Memory Utilization Metric of EKS nodes to cloudwatch
I have an EKS cluster that spawn EC2 instances inside of node groups. I can check the CPU utilization of the EC2 instances inside EKS using cloudwatch. I want to monitor the memory utilization as well. Is there any way to export the memory utilization metric to cloudwatch as well. We can export metric of independent EC2 instances using this method. I am not sure how to do something similar for the nodes inside EKS

You can achieve this with EKS Container Insights, quickest way to activate the addon is here.
